# Misbehaving Service behviors

Tags: c#, winforms, wcf, debugging

Basically I'm making  a program to simulate a petrol station system.

My problem is that I'm trying to send a request through a WCF service such as this:

```
User Requests Pump to be activated ----> WCF SERVICE ---->  Point of Sale
User starts pumping petrol<---- WCF SERVICE <----  Point of Sale Accepts
```

At the moment it works, but only sometimes.

This is how I try to get a response:

```
 while(PumpserviceClient.getRequestedAcceptedStatusFromPos().Accepted == false)
 {
    PumpserviceClient.RequestPump(int.Parse(PumpID));
    // needs to wait for pump to be activated
    if (PumpserviceClient.getRequestedAcceptedStatusFromPos().Accepted == true /*&& PumpserviceClient.getRequestedAcceptedStatusFromPos().PumpNo == int.Parse(PumpID)*/)
    {
       MessageBox.Show(" The Pos has accepted your pump request");
       // if its accepted you call
       Customer.ActivatePump();
    }
```

And these are the methods in the service:

```
bool Accepted= false;
bool Requested=false;
public void AcceptPump(int PumpNumber)
{
   Accepted = true;
   Requested = false;
   int pumpnumber = PumpNumber;
   PumpRequest.Accepted = Accepted;
   PumpRequest.Requested = Requested;
}

public void RequestPump(int PumpNumber)
{
   int pumpnumber = PumpNumber;
   Requested = true;
   Accepted = false;

   PumpRequest.Accepted = Accepted;
   PumpRequest.PumpNo = PumpNumber;
   PumpRequest.Requested = Requested;
}

public void ResetRequest(int PumpNumber)
{
   int pumpnumber = PumpNumber;
   Requested = false;
   Accepted = false;

   PumpRequest.Accepted = Accepted;
   PumpRequest.PumpNo = 0;
   PumpRequest.Requested = Requested;
}

public Message getRequestedStatusFromPump()
{
   return PumpRequest;
}

public Message getRequestedAcceptedStatusFromPos()
{
   return PumpRequest;
}
```

}

and the point of sale system accepts the requests by:

```
if (Client.getRequestedStatusFromPump().Requested == true)
{
   MessageBox.Show("Pump Number: "+Client.getRequestedStatusFromPump().PumpNo + " Is waiting to be accepted");
   // need to press a button or something
   Client.AcceptPump(Client.getRequestedStatusFromPump().PumpNo);
}
```

Code here http://www.pastebucket.com/8642

Comment: It only works sometimes. Okay, what happens otherwise?

Comment: Do you get errors? What are the circumstances when it doesn't work? What happens when it doesn't work? Did you spank the misbehaving service?

Comment: Sorry, When it doesn't work " MessageBox.Show(" The Pos has accepted your pump request");
                            // if its accepted you call
                            Customer.ActivatePump();
" Doesn't call

Comment: Where's the code for `ActivatePump()`? Theory is that you're setting the `Accepted` to `true`, and never calling the `ResetRequest()`.

Comment: I don't understand why `pumpnumber` (note lowercase) is local for all these functions.  You do know this is not shared with anything else once those functions end?  It seems to do nothing.  If it does nothing why have this variable at all?  Remove it.

Comment: It doesn't need to be there, It's from a previous attempt, that's not really doing anything but it's literally just a reference as to which of my clients is waiting for a response

Comment: @RhysDrury: You've got your code listed here in piece meal, and it's hard to determine what's going on. Please post the full code, so that we can better help you.

Comment: Added a link to the code, http://www.pastebucket.com/8642

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read the code posted.  You use the following attribute:

```
 [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
```

This means your code will not multi-thread.  But there is no guarantee multiple sessions won't make requests and "interrupt" each other's workflow.

For example:

1. Client A calls request pump
2. Client B calls reset pump
3. Client A reads... client A wonders why pump was reset.

Your code is written expecting the object to be by session.  I'd suggest using this context mode and seeing if you have better luck.

The other option is to add session information to your model.  I can't imagine why this would be useful.  It certainly won't be easy.

Comment: I tried changing the context mode and nothing seemed to happen, I think I'm just going to have to think of a different way to accept each pump. But thanks for your help anyway

Comment: hmmm... you could try deleting this question and asking again with the full source available.

Comment: I might do, At the minute my PoS client can view all the pumps as they send information across and because all they do is send to a list and the PoS reads the list and filters by Pump ID it works fine.

I almost  need to have each pump have its own section or list for the PoS to get and set, then there would be no interuptions. I'm just unsure how to do that

Comment: @RhysDrury - like I said... each having it's own is "by session".

Comment: I fixed the problem, but I did it by making a list that sets each pump its own pumpsession class depending on the number, so pump one is in index 1 etc. Then the service doesn't get confused between each one.

Answer (score 0):

The only way i found around this problem, without changing service behaviors was to create a new list

```
 public void CreatePumpList()
    {
        WaitingPumps = new List<WaitingPumps>();
        for (int i = 0; i < PumpLimit+1 ; i++)
        {
            WaitingPumps.Add(new WaitingPumps());
        }
    }
```

Then just use the pump Number as the index in this list so they don't get confused with each other.